# Hiding a textfield on an external website form

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to hide a text field on the form of a website. The text field is currently not hidden and I've heard that I could be able to hide it from view by overlaying an external style sheet.

EDIT: The website isn't mine and I have no control of the source etc, I need to be able to do this without touching their code. The reason we need to be able to do this is to send a credit card number to this field from a session variable (obtained by DTMF tones and an IVR) without the person sat in front of the computer being able to see what's been inputted.

I don't want to hide it from EVERYONE, just the people who work for us and access it through our PC's.

Is this possible?

Thanks,

Comment: ..un-ethical hacking ? or could you describe the problem a bit better ?

Comment: Hide it from whom? Arbitrary people who visit someone else's website? No.

Comment: @John youre saying you only need to hide the text field on ONE specific computer?

Comment: It will be a bank of around 10 computers.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Add  the following css class:

```
display:none;
```

Comment: I don't mean to nitpick (or Do I?! :) ), but that's not a css class, it's a style (which make up CSS classes) :)

Comment: The website isn't mine and I have no control of the source etc, I need to be able to do this without touching their code.

Comment: Why are you trying to change a website that is not yours and you have no control over...?

Comment: Well without touching their code there is no permanent way of doing this. For one time visual purposes, you can use Firebug, or any built in browser developer tools really, and just add your own css code or disable the element.

Comment: @Moo-Juice — "CSS rule sets". There is no such thing as a "CSS class" but the term is sometimes used to mean "rule set", "selector", "class selector" and "HTML class".

Answer (score 0):

yes you can

CSS Approch

use css `display:none;`

Or use javascript

```
      var child = document.getElementById(childDiv);
      var parent = document.getElementById(parentDiv);
      parent.removeChild(child);
```

Comment: The website isn't mine and I have no control of the source etc, I need to be able to do this without touching their code.

Comment: Then you can change it only in your machine :( by using some scripts with the help grease monkey like addons

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you are allowed to do, and whether these machines are only used for that site, you can create a page with an `iframe` holding the site you want and then overlay what you need.

It might be tricky if the page is scrollable, or the user can alter the size of text etc (*cause reflows to the content*)

```
<iframe src="http://url.to.actual.page"></iframe>
<div class="distractor">Position me on top of the iframe to hide some content</div>
```

and

```
iframe{
    width:600px; /* as needed */
    height:300px;
    overflow:hidden;
    z-index:1;
    position:relative;
}

.distractor{
    position:absolute;
    background-color:red; /* color it as the background of the page */

    top:80px; /* position it where you need it */
    left:100px;

    width:100px; /* size it as you need it */
    height:100px;

    z-index:1000;
}
```

demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/GemC2/1/

Not a great solution, but might give you some ideas..

---

Another solution, if you are allowed to use plugins to browsers is to set [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/), and install a custom script that will hide the input you need.

Or [Stylish](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stylish/) and set a custom CSS style to override the page's style.